# Changing the field type of a column to a custom field type

Tags: custom-field-types

Here's the situation: I have a site column of type Choice that is used in content types and libraries. Document libraries contain items.  So the site column is currently used. I have created a custom field type and I would like to the site column to used this new custom field type.

Is it possible to change the field type of a site column through code? Maybe with spfield.schemaxml?  Or will I have to create a new site column based on the new field type, move all the existing data to the new column and delete the original column?

Note that the custom field type (ParentType=Choice) was createad to have custom RenderPattern (display).

(This is for MOSS 2007)

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a new site column and migrate the data across.

Comment: exactly. it gets cached from here to high hell, so creating a new field is the only thing that i have got working